# Error with unistalling a theme through Magento-Connect

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme, magento-connect

Trying to uninstall magento_classic_theme_free, through Magento connect and it is giving me the following error.

**"Starting to uninstall community/magento_classic_theme_free
CONNECT ERROR: Failed to delete files: /public_html/a-mag-data/magento/downloader/.././app/design/default/default/layout/tmcore.xml
Check permissions"**

And now I can't even get to the front or the back-end. It is showing me 
Service Temporarily Unavailable

**The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.**

What a nightmare!

Comment: this is because a maintanence.flag file generated in your root floder where app skin folders resides..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. First check your root folder and delete maintenance.flag
2. Give downloader folder full permission

Then you are good to go.

Comment: I deleted it and now I'm getting:There has been an error processing your request

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 230679353353

Comment: check the log content in var/log and tell

Comment: '2015-05-28T05:09:31+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: scandir(/home/********/public_html/********/magento/downloader/.././app/code/community/TM/Core/Block/Adminhtml/Module/Grid/Renderer): failed to open dir: No such file or directory  in /home/********/public_html/********/magento/downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Packager.php on line 243`

Comment: 2015-05-28T05:09:31+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: scandir(): (errno 2): No such file or directory  in /home/********/public_html/********/magento/downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Packager.php on line 243

Comment: The issue occured because the removal process was stuck in the middle and depended files gone missing. Please try disabling the module in app/etc/modules and let me know

Comment: open the module file.. might be something like tm.xml. then change true to false. Save and up. refresh cache as well..

Comment: What module to disable?  There is no module called tm.xml.  Stackexchange Wants me to move this to chat???

Comment: there should be a file related to that module in app/etc/modules folder

Comment: There are Mage_All.xml, Mag_Api.xml, MaG_Api2.xml, Mage_Authorizenet.xml, Mage_Bundle.xml, Mage_Captcha.xml, Mage_Centinel.xml, Mage_Compiler.xml, Mage_ConfigurableSwatches.xml, Mage_Connect.xml, Mage_CurrencySymbol.xml, Mage_Downloadable.xml, Mage_ImportExport.xml, Mage_Oauth.xml,Mage_PageCache.xml, Mage_Persistent.xml, Mage_Weee.xml, Mage_Widget.xml, Mage_XmlConnect.xml, MagePsycho_Easypathhints.xml and Phoenix_Moneybookers.xml That's all.

Comment: did you took backup before doing this?

Comment: No Backups. No worries, It's on a test site. But this is the second time this is happening. I wanted to test another theme other than rwd and picked that one.  And then when I went back to rwd, the zoom stopped functioning.   So I wanted to remove the newly added theme. That's when things hit the fan...   The only folder I see their is magento/app/design/default/default/layout/tmcore.xml/ which is empty.  Am I toast?

Comment: Oh by the way,  /tmcore.xml/ has 777 permissions. And it was pointing to that folder from Magento-Connect as follow: **"Starting to uninstall community/magento_classic_theme_free CONNECT ERROR: Failed to delete files: /public_html/a-mag-data/magento/downloader/.././app/design/default/default/layout/tmcore.xml Check permissions"**