# "Check permissions" Extension Uninstall Error Magento connect

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-connect-manager

Trying to uninstall the extension by Magento connect but am getting

```
/var/www/mageboy/downloader/.././app/design//app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/outofstocknotification/widget/grid.phtml
```

**Check permissions**

I have followed some magento.stackexchange answers but I can not find the solution. like
[Error with unistalling a theme through Magento-Connect](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/69267/error-with-unistalling-a-theme-through-magento-connect)

Answer (score 1):

The file's path does not seem to be correct. Anyway, try to connect your server via SSH and execute the following command

```
ls /var/www/mageboy/app/design/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/outofstocknotification/widget/
```

If you get the `grid.phtml` among the listed files - try to set correct permissions for the entire directory:

```
chmod -R 755 /var/www/mageboy/app/design/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/outofstocknotification/widget/
```

If you get something like "No such file or directory" instead of the list of files for the first `ls` command - unfortunately, Magento downloader registered a wrong path for the mentioned file. In that case the easiest way is to remove the entire extension manually.

Comment: Not only the only file but total extension , I have removed every file related to Extension manually by searching 'grep -i -n -r' but still it is in Connect manager.  i have submitted two extensions to M-connect those are live , when i am trying to un install both by connect manager ".......:( “Check permissions”. Please Help

Comment: Actually, it's a bit tricky deal to remove a record from the Magento Connect configuration. The configuration is stored in /downloader/cache.cfg . You can try to decode it, remove the record and encode back like Alan mentioned here http://goo.gl/Qws1pj . Or you can try to sync all your extensions with Magento Connect in order to rebuild your cache.cfg file like it mentioned here http://goo.gl/d7aHXE . Anyway, if you have removed the extension manually - you may not bother with the 'chunk' in the cache.cfg, it should not cause issues for the store's functionality but might cost you many hours

Comment: Great in-depth answer  , but It is happening for every installation for every customer . Do i need to modify anything in my extensions ( Out of stock Noti, Category slider )?. In the same time i have tried to uninstall example extension by using Magento connect replies " Package deleted: Cache cleaned successfully".

Comment: First of all, try to check package.xml inside of your packed extension. There you will find XML tree of the extension's directories/files and their hashsums. You might find the broken path (...app/design/app/design/...) there.